# nginx errors resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, nginx

I am stracing nginx on a linux box  to see if it is picking all the right (zipped) files. I see quite a few error messages like this

```
"recvfrom(10, 0x13a3f00, 1024, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)".
```

The web site is working fine all right. I would like to find out what is causing these errors.

Any ideas? Is this a problem? Sample messages with lines before/after

```
gettimeofday({1393091093, 449276}, NULL) = 0
recvfrom(10, 0x7fff41fa3ebf, 1, 2, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(11, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, {u32=622124241, u64=139634303884497}}}, 512, 59997) = 1
gettimeofday({1393091094, 51237}, NULL) = 0

setsockopt(10, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
recvfrom(10, 0x13a3f00, 1024, 0, 0, 0)  = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(11, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=622120976, u64=139634303881232}}}, 512, 65000) = 1


recvfrom(14, 0x7fff41fa2db0, 4096, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(11, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=622124241, u64=139634303884497}}}, 512, 5000) = 1


shutdown(10, 1 /* send */)              = 0
recvfrom(10, 0x7fff41fa2db0, 4096, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_wait(11, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=622125584, u64=139634303885840}}}, 512, 5000) = 1
```